# Is there a way to print a list of the most important features of an Light GBM Classifier model?

Tags: python, lightgbm

Running an LGBM Classifier model and I'm able to use lgbm.plot_importance to plot the most important features but I would prefer having a list of these features instead, does anybody know how to go about doing this?

Comment: Does `model.feature_importance()` work for you?

Comment: It's not working for me. I keep getting this error: 'LGBMClassifier' object has no attribute 'feature_importance'

Answer (score 3):

The `lightgbm.Booster` object has a method `.feature_importance()` which can be used to access feature importances.

That method returns an array with one importance value per feature, and supports two types of importance, based on the value of `importance_type`:

- `"gain"` = "cumulative gain of all splits using this feature"
- `"split"` = "number of splits this feature was used in"

You can explore this using the following code. I ran this with `lightgbm==3.3.0`, `numpy==1.21.0`, `pandas==1.2.3`, and `scikit-learn==0.24.1`, using Python 3.8.

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)
data = lgb.Dataset(X, label=y)

# train model
bst = lgb.train(
    params={"objective": "binary"},
    train_set=data,
    num_boost_round=10
)

# compute importances
importance_df = (
    pd.DataFrame({
        'feature_name': bst.feature_name(),
        'importance_gain': bst.feature_importance(importance_type='gain'),
        'importance_split': bst.feature_importance(importance_type='split'),
    })
    .sort_values('importance_gain', ascending=False)
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
print(importance_df)
```

Here's an example of the output.

```
   feature_name  importance_gain  importance_split
0     Column_22      1051.204456                 8
1     Column_23       862.363854                10
2     Column_27       262.272097                19
3      Column_7       161.842017                13
4     Column_21        66.431762                24
```

This is saying that, for example, feature `Column_21`  was used in more splits than other top features, but the improvement those splits provided were much less impactful than the 8 splits using `Column_22`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using Sklearn API for Lightgbm. This should help.
General idea:

```
LGBMClassifier.feature_importances_
```

Particular case:

```
model_name.feature_importances_
```

Full code snippet (assuming pandas dataframe was used for training):

```
features = train_x.columns
importances = model.feature_importances_
feature_importance = pd.DataFrame({'importance':importances,'features':features}).sort_values('importance', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
feature_importance
```

Also you can plot importances:

```
lgb.plot_importance(model_name)
```